# Forcing window focus on firefox or chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox

At work I had a very... peculiar demand. So I'm pretty sure it is clearly not doable, and couldn't find any working answer on the internet (I tried onblur="self.focus();" on  but it didn't work and it broke FF inspector).

The idea is as follows:

- The user is using the web application as its main CRM tool and must not be able to hide it with other windows.
- It doesn't need to always have focus, only to be always on top.

I'm pretty sure this is clearly not doable only with client-side JavaScript and would require a module, but any suggestion is welcome, and since we will configure the user browser (and computer) we can definitely go the module way.

I'm not sure if the question is very clear so feel free to ask!

Thanks in advance :]

EDIT: Since I forgot to mention it before, we are working only on Ubuntu 16.04+ :]

Comment: Why is those requirements necessary?  I think that this will have negative impact on work flow

Comment: Apparently the end user isn't "initiated" enough to be able to retrieve the window by himself and must be babysitted so he/she never loses the window. This is what comes out the book of specifications, so I'm trying my best to meet this requirement :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to do that with javascript.

I know the application [Always On Top Maker](https://always-on-top-maker.en.softonic.com/) where you can manually put any application window always on top.

Since the application "Always On Top Maker" is running, the user should press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to toggle always on top status of current active window.

if <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>Q</kbd> is pressed, the "Always On Top Maker" application exits.

This is only for windows.

EDIT:
For Ubuntu try [https://www.maketecheasier.com/keyboard-shortcut-for-always-on-top-ubuntu](https://www.maketecheasier.com/keyboard-shortcut-for-always-on-top-ubuntu/) that explain how to make a individual window always on top.

Comment: This is definitely an interesting solution, and it makes me realize I didn't give you the destination OS (silly me) so I'll put it here and edit my question. We are working only on Ubuntu 16.04+ :(

Comment: Thanks for your edit, that's definitely a good solution for this issue as it is obviously impossible through JavaScript alone. I think this is the way we will do it. Thanks again for your help!